# How to change height of the header on each region

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm wondering how to change height of the header.

from my research, there is a value to get height of the header with below script.

```
# get height of 'HEADER' region on 'INFO' area
>>> bpy.context.screen.areas[0].regions[0].height
52
```

However, above script can not be used to set height because above value is readonly.

```
# error!! (height is readonly value)
>>> bpy.context.screen.areas[0].regions[0].height = 100
```

Could you tell me if there is there any method to set height of the header?

Thanks.